# Turn Photoshop (CS5) Selection into Polygon Coordinates

Tags: google-maps, photoshop, polygon, imagemap

I am trying to find the polygon coordinates of a custom Google Maps marker PNG I am using in a current project with Photoshop CS5. I have made the selection, and am hoping that selection can be exported into a coordinate set like so: (x,y,x,y,x,y). Here's an illustration:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: I didn't get the question, why and what coordinates do you need?

Comment: @refhat I need the coordinates of the selection relative to the size of the image itself. EXAMPLE: say the image is 20x35 pixels and the first point of the polygon is at the base of the marker image. In this case, the first latLng pair will be something like 10, 33. I want to "draw" the shape of the marker with Google Maps API V3 to get a more exact :hover state for the marker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the better way to find coordinated of the marker is to use vector graphics soft like Adobe Illustrator. You can create this map marker as vector and save it as SVG (as I did it in 20 sec).

You can download here: http://www.mediafire.com/download/2y78sgb8vwdhbfd/google-marker.svg

By saving SVG graphics in Illustrator you will see a button "Show SVG code". When you click it you will find the following code on the bottom:

```
...
<rect fill="none" width="127" height="153"/>
<path fill="#ED1C24" d="M118,58.25c0,29.961-54.25,81.25-54.25,81.25S9.5,88.211,9.5,58.25S33.789,4,63.75,4S118,28.289,118,58.25z"
...
```

As you can see there is a width/height of the graphics and coordinates for every dot of the path.

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Thanks, Nekto. This is a great idea. I just completely forgot to mark this as the answer. My apologies.